# D7 form_set_value : Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Tags: forms

I want to use the function form_set_value to replace a taxonomy vocabulary by an other in my form. What's happend if the value is not a string, but an object. In this case I have an error.

The form element looks like this `$form['field_arborescence']['und'][0]['tid']['shs_vocabulary']->vid` (=2, ->name= 'vocabulary 1', ->machine_name = 'vocabulary_2' ...)
and `$form['#parents'] = array('field_arborescence','und',0,'tid','shs_vocabulary')`

The new value if form_set_value is an object : ->vid = 3, ->name = 'vocabulary 2, ->machine_name ='vocabulary 2' (from taxonomy_vocabulary_load)

I got the error 'Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in ...form.inc'

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Change the 1 submitted value on form submission to something else in your form validate function? Or, change what options the user sees when they goto the form.

Comment: Can you please include a real sample of your code and explain where you have used it?